# Aruba/HPE 5400R ZL VLAN Interface not pinging

Tags: vlan, hp-procurve, aruba

I think that this will be a simple one.

I am attempting to set up an Aruba/HPE 5412R ZL2 Chassis switch. I have set up several VLANs on the switch and have got routing working between them. All of the VLANs have IP addresses assigned to them.

However, the addresses that I assign the VLANs can't be reached unless the VLAN has some tagged/untagged ports and something has been plugged into one of these ports. This suggests to me that the switch is selectively disabling the IP addresses until something is connected. For at least one of the VLANs, I'd prefer that the switch didn't do this because this IP address will be the one I designate as the management IP.

Other 5400 switches that I have on the network (which weren't configured by me) have VLAN addresses which aren't assigned to anything but can still be pinged so I think there must be an enable command somewhere, I just can't find it. Can anyone make any suggestions?

Switch config is as follows (still incomplete):

```
    Running configuration:

    ; J9851A Configuration Editor; Created on release #KB.16.04.0009
    ; Ver #11:10.9b.7f.bf.bb.ff.7c.59.fc.7b.ff.ff.fc.ff.ff.3f.ef:90
    hostname "HTGFS-CoreSw-HubRm-001"
    module A type j9986a
    module B type j9986a
    module C type j9986a
    module D type j9986a
    module E type j9986a
    module F type j9986a
    module K type j9990a
    module L type j9990a
    console idle-timeout 2400
    console idle-timeout serial-usb 2400
    trunk K23-K24,L23-L24 trk1 lacp
    mvrp enable
    telnet-server listen data
    web-management listen data
    ip access-list extended "WirelessNetworks"
         10 deny ip 172.24.0.0 0.0.255.255 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255
         20 deny ip 172.21.0.0 0.0.255.255 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255
         30 deny ip 172.22.0.0 0.0.255.255 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255
         40 deny ip 172.23.0.0 0.0.255.255 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255
         50 deny ip 172.25.0.0 0.0.255.255 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255
         60 deny ip 172.26.0.0 0.0.255.255 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255
         70 deny ip 172.27.0.0 0.0.255.255 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255
         80 deny ip 172.28.0.0 0.0.255.255 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255
         90 deny ip 172.29.0.0 0.0.255.255 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255
         100 deny ip 172.30.0.0 0.0.255.255 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255
         110 permit ip 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255
       exit
    ip ssh listen data
    ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.150
    ip route 172.16.0.0 255.255.0.0 192.168.1.1
    ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
    ip router-id 10.0.0.2
    ip routing
    ip multicast-routing
    snmp-server community "public" unrestricted
    snmp-server listen data
    oobm
       disable
       no ip address
       exit
    router ospf
       area backbone
       redistribute connected
       enable
       exit
    router pim
       enable
       exit
    vlan 1
       name "DEFAULT_VLAN"
       no untagged
     A1-A24,B1-B24,C1-C24,D1-D24,E1-E24,F1-F24,K1-K14,K17-K20,L1-L14,L17-L19
       untagged K15-K16,K21-K22,L15-L16,L20-L22,Trk1
       no ip address
       exit
    vlan 56
       name "***CCTV***"
       untagged K17-K20,L17-L19
       tagged L20,Trk1
       no ip address
       ip igmp
       exit
    vlan 100
       name "WAN"
       tagged L20,Trk1
       ip address 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.0
       ip address 192.168.1.20 255.255.240.0
       ip igmp
       ip ospf 10.0.0.2 area backbone
       exit
    vlan 140
       name "Free School Data Range 1"
       untagged A1-A24,C1-C24,E1-E24
       ip address 10.2.140.1 255.255.254.0
       ip helper-address 10.5.200.10
       ip helper-address 10.5.200.11
       ip igmp
       exit
    vlan 144
       name "Free School Data Range 2"
       untagged B1-B24,D1-D24,F1-F24
       ip address 10.2.144.1 255.255.254.0
       ip helper-address 10.5.200.10
       ip helper-address 10.5.200.11
       ip igmp
       exit
    vlan 200
       name "Free School Server Range"
       untagged K1,L1
       ip address 10.2.200.1 255.255.255.0
       ip helper-address 10.5.200.11
       ip helper-address 10.5.200.10
       ip igmp
       exit
    vlan 210
       name "Free School Server Management"
       untagged K2,L2
       ip address 10.2.210.1 255.255.255.0
       ip igmp
       exit
    vlan 212
       name "Free School Network Management"
       ip address 10.2.212.1 255.255.255.0
       exit
    vlan 214
       name "Free School Wifi Management"
       untagged K3-K14,L3-L14
       ip address 10.2.214.1 255.255.255.0
       ip helper-address 10.5.200.10
       ip helper-address 10.5.200.11
       exit
    vlan 218
       name "CCTV"
       ip address 10.2.218.1 255.255.255.0
       ip igmp
       exit
    vlan 220
       name "Voice"
       tagged A1-A24,B1-B24,C1-C24,D1-D24,E1-E24,F1-F24,K1-K20,L1-L19
       ip address 10.2.220.1 255.255.255.0
       ip helper-address 10.5.200.10
       ip helper-address 10.5.200.11
       ip igmp
       voice
       exit
    vlan 222
       name "Free School Guest Wifi"
       tagged A1-A24,B1-B24,C1-C24,D1-D24,E1-E24,F1-F24,K1-K20,L1-L19
       ip address 172.22.16.1 255.255.252.0
       ip helper-address 10.5.200.10
       ip helper-address 10.5.200.11
       ip igmp
       exit
    vlan 224
       name "Free School Trusted Wifi"
       tagged A1-A24,B1-B24,C1-C24,D1-D24,E1-E24,F1-F24,K1-K20,L1-L19
       ip address 10.2.224.1 255.255.240.0
       ip helper-address 10.5.200.10
       ip helper-address 10.5.200.11
       ip igmp
       exit
    vlan 240
       name "Free School BYOD Wifi"
       tagged A1-A24,B1-B24,C1-C24,D1-D24,E1-E24,F1-F24,K1-K20,L1-L19
       ip address 172.22.0.1 255.255.248.0
       ip helper-address 10.5.200.11
       ip helper-address 10.5.200.10
       exit
    spanning-tree
    spanning-tree A1 admin-edge-port
    spanning-tree A1 bpdu-protection
    <same spanning tree config for the other ports>
    spanning-tree Trk1 priority 4
    spanning-tree bpdu-protection-timeout 300 priority 0
    tftp server listen data
    loop-protect A1-A24,B1-B24,C1-C24,D1-D24,E1-E24,F1-F24,K1-K20,L1-L19
    loop-protect disable-timer 10
```

The VLAN interfaces that I can't ping are 212 and 218, either from the switch's management interface or from a computer attached to the network. 212 is likely never to have any ports (un)tagged.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Cisco switches allow you to disable the auto state function on an SVI, which would give you what you want, but I’m not aware of an equivalent feature on Aruba/Procurve switches.  An alternative would be to add the VLAN as a tagged VLAN for one of the ports you know will always be up.

Could I suggest as an alternative solution that you create a loopback interface and advertise that into OSPF and use that as the management IP?  That would be a better management solution in my opinion and the IP would always be up.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, thank you. I’ll give it a try in the morning.

Comment: Perfect, thankyou. This switch is for a separate segment of our network and is combining core and edge. It's unlikely that there will be any other switches in this segment so tagging a port wasn't a good solution for me in this instance. Creating a loopback interface and giving it the IP address I want to use for management has worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

As Vlan 212 is network management Vlan, you should have it *configured* across your network and *tagged* on uplink (switch-switch links) ports, then it would be up and you could ping/reach it from other subnets.

According to [HP document](ftp://ftp.hp.com/%2F/pub/networking/software/AdvTraff-Oct2005-59908853-Chap02-VLAN.pdf)

> **IP Interfaces**
>
> There is a one-to-one relationship between a VLAN and an IP network
>   interface. Since the VLAN is defined by a group of ports, the state
>   (up/down) of those ports determines the state of the IP network
>   interface associated with that VLAN. When a VLAN comes up because one
>   or more of its ports is up, the IP interface for that VLAN is also
>   activated. Likewise, when a VLAN is deactivated because all of its
>   ports are down, the corresponding IP interface is also deactivated.